# Pass many pieces of data from Python to C program

Tags: python, c, dll, parameter-passing

I have a Python script and a C program and I need to pass large quantities of data from Python script that call many times the C program. Right now I let the user choose between passing them with an ASCII file or a binary file, but both are quite slow and useless (I mean files are useful if you want to store the data, but I delete these files at the end of the script).

`os.system` doesn't work, the arguments are too much as the C program too uses files to return data to Python, but this is much less data.

I wonder what I can use to make this exchange fast. Writing the files to a RAM disk? If so, how can I do this?

I heard is possible to call functions from DLL using ctypes, but don't know how to compile my program as a DLL (I use wxdevc+ on Windows 7 64).
Or wrap it, but still don't know if it can work and if it is efficient.

The data are vertices of a 3D mesh.

I'm running the Python script inside another program ([blender](http://www.blender.org/) (open source), and is called many times (usually more than 500 times) because it's inside a cycle. The script send vertices information (1 `int` index and 3 float coords) to the program, and the program should return many vertices (only int index, because I can find the corresponding vertices with Python).

So this is not interactive, it's more like a function (but it's wrote in C). The script + C program (that are add-ons of blender) that I'm writing should be cross-platform because it will be redistributed.

The program is actually wrote in C, and from Python I can know the address in memory of the struct that contains the vertices data. If only I know how to do this, should be better to pass to the C program only an address, and from there find all the other vertices (are stored in list).

But as far as I know, I can't access to the memory space of another program, and I don't know if calling the program with pipes or whatever initialize a new thread or is run inside the script (that is actually run under the Blender thread)

[Here is the source](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/blender/) and `blender/source/blender/makesdna/DNA_meshdata_types.h` should be the struct definition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pipes are the obvious way to go; if your c program accepts input from stdin, you can use `Popen`. This doesn't create a "thread" as you say in your edit; it creates an *entirely new process* with separate memory:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

input = "some input"
cproc = Popen("c_prog", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
out, err = cproc.communicate(input)
```

Here's a more detailed example. First, a simple c program that echoes stdin:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define BUFMAX 100

int main() {
    char buffer[BUFMAX + 1];
    char *bp = buffer;
    int c;
    FILE *in;
    while (EOF != (c = fgetc(stdin)) && (bp - buffer) < BUFMAX) {
        *bp++ = c;
    }
    *bp = 0;    // Null-terminate the string
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Then a python program that pipes input (from argv in this case) to the above:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from sys import argv

input = ' '.join(argv[1:])
if not input: input = "no arguments given"
cproc = Popen("./c_prog", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
out, err = cproc.communicate(input)
print "output:", out
print "errors:", err
```

If you don't plan to use the c program without the python frontend, though, you might be better off inlining a c function, perhaps using `instant`.

```
from instant import inline
c_code = """
    [ ... some c code ... ] //see the below page for a more complete example.
"""
c_func = inline(c_code)
```

As Joe points out, you could also write a python module in c: [Extending Python with C or C++](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html)

This answer discusses other ways to combine c and python: [How do I connect a Python and a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743748/how-do-i-connect-a-python-and-a-c-program)

EDIT: Based on your edit, it sounds like you really should create a cpython extension. If you want some example code, let me know; but a full explanation would make for a unreasonably long answer. See the link above (Extending Python...) for everything you need to know.

Comment: i wrote the C program, i can change how i want. So communicating something with pipes is like writing in the stdin?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. I'll post an example just in case.

Comment: Ok, i undersood your code. Unfortunately i'll have redistribute the code, so i prefer to use only standard libraries(i saw that instant is an extern library). I'll try with pipes.
And i bother you a bit more: do you think making a shared library and calling it with ctypes would work as well?
Btw really interesting the inline thing!

Answer (score 4):

If your operating system supports it, [named pipes](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkfifo) are a drop in replacement for files.

Answer (score 3):

I've never been satisfied with the answers of linking python and C so I wrote an answer after a good deal of research and thinking.

Test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char path[1035];

    fp = popen("python3 output2.py", "r");  // Open the command for reading.
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path), fp) != NULL)
       printf("C received %s", path);  // Read the output. 

    pclose(fp);  // close 

   return 0;
}
```

output2.py

```
import time
import os, sys

i = 0
while True :
    print("%d" %(i), flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to connect cliquer https://users.aalto.fi/~pat/cliquer.html to python?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea slightly different from the others: Write your C program as a Python module. [Here](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html) is all the information you need to do it. You can then pass large buffers back and forth between your Python code and your C code.

Comment: Do you know how I can connect cliquer https://users.aalto.fi/~pat/cliquer.html to python? since python takes days to calculate this specific math problem, I want to push the calculations to C