# How do I connect a Python and a C program in windows using pycharm?

Tags: python, c, pycharm, clique, clique-problem

I have a Python program that must send the number of nodes and graphs to a C program for faster computation ([called cliquer](https://users.aalto.fi/pat/cliquer.html)). The C program(the executable is better since it should be faster) then computes the cliques and returns them to Python, which computes the other parameters. It is very important that I create such an automatic pipeline since the calculation process is very slow.
I've looked around the internet and everything I've found is Linux-based.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we use C code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762621/can-we-use-c-code-in-python)

Comment: What do you mean "C program"? C source code or some executable?

Comment: @GinoMempin  I want to somehow connect these two, python and C (I heard that if the C program is compiled it is faster right?)

Comment: @gre_gor executable is much preferable since it will run faster, am I right?

Comment: Old [experimental Python wrapper for cliquer](https://github.com/braincorp/clique_python_wrapper). May not be viable now but maybe something to look at.

Comment: @jarmod I was trying to run the file but it seems a file is missing `from clique_python_wrapper._wrapper_max_weighted_clique_module import find_max_weighted_clique as find_max_weighted_clique_impl `

Comment: @jarmod This is the error:
` from clique_python_wrapper._wrapper_max_weighted_clique_module import find_max_weighted_clique as find_max_weighted_clique_impl 
ImportError: No module named _wrapper_max_weighted_clique_module`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass many pieces of data from Python to C program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4961267/2745495)