# Run C program from Python and then capture output

Tags: python, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I connect a Python and a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743748/how-do-i-connect-a-python-and-a-c-program)

I have a C program that takes two args and outputs a number.

./a.out 2 3 (for example). It does some computational expensive operations, so I was wondering could I use Python's multiprocessing library to run a bunch of the C programs and then compile all the numbers into a list or table or some data structure?

Thanks,

This is not a duplicate because my questions is how can i do it IN PARALLEL EX. MANY THREADS!

Comment: What have you tried? Are none of the Google results similar to your question working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Your C file to be called from python
// To compile :
// gcc -dynamiclib -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -lpython2.7 -o Module.dylib Module.c

#include < Python.h >

static PyObject* py_myFunction(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    char *s = "Hello from C!";
    return Py_BuildValue("s", s);
}

static PyMethodDef myModule_methods[] = {
    {"myFunction", py_myFunction, METH_VARAGS},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

void initmyModule()
{
    (void) Py_InitModule("myModule", myModule_methods);
}
```

To call from python:

```
from Module import *
print "Result from myFunction:", myFunction()
```

Comment: Wow, that's great to include a code sample ... but Stack Overflow has built-in code formatting so you don't have to do it manually. Simply paste the original code directly into the answer, highlight it, and press the `{}` button or Ctrl+K. That will indent it all by four spaces, which will format it correctly with syntax highlighting.