# How to speed up: opening a data file in python

Tags: python, excel, bigdata

I am using a simple code line to open a big data .xls file `workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('file_name.xls')`. It also takes considerable time to execute. I am using Python 2. Is there a way to speed up this step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On demand access to the work book would reduce the memory usage that might considerably reduce the loading time. Try the following code

```
import xlrd
try:
    work_book = xlrd.open_workbook('file_name.xls', on_demand=True)
finally:
    work_book.release_resources()
```

PS - don't forget to release the resources

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to break the file up into multiple parts and use multithreading (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm).

However, there is a reason Python is not known for being the fastest language in the world...  Consider approaching this problem with a different language (if possible).

You could also launch a C program from within Python to do this for you.  You will most likely see some significant improvement. [Run C program from Python and then capture output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870143/run-c-program-from-python-and-then-capture-output)